# Ramifications of using homebrew instead of apt package manager?

Tags: apt, package-management

So I am running Ubuntu 18.04 as my desktop machine on my new laptop.  I am using this primarily for development.

Some services I want to use are using older versions like redis, go progrmaming language versions etc.  I end up googling around and this usually requires me to manually install or add repositories etc. if I use apt.

What are the ramifications if I use homebrew?

I didn't realize it works on linux.  Will this cause potential conflicts with apt related packages?

Comment: I had locale issues they turn out to be caused to the fact that Homebrew add a second glibc to your system, usually on `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/glibc/`. On the other hand, the amount of tools brew provides is huge.

Answer (score 3):

The current LTS (18.04) is nearly two years old. Since Debian and Ubuntu use a *snapshot release* model (not a *rolling release* model) most of the software in those two-year-old repositories will be --you guessed it-- of roughly equivalent age. This [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/) explains in much more detail.

For newer software, try a newer release of Ubuntu. Most Ubuntu developers that I know use the latest release, not the LTS. It depends what you are developing for.

Homebrew installs to a different location than apt or pip or other common package mangers, so *conflicts* seem to be rare. However, most package mangers only keep track of their own packages, be prepared for a bit of bloat as many of your libs are promptly duplicated in the new location.

Dependencies installed by Homebrew CANNOT be used for Deb packages - only deb dependencies can be used for debs.

Dependencies installed by Homebrew CAN be used for Snap packages, though it will take a bit of work since [current snap tools](https://snapcraft.io/build) don't look for Homebrew packages.

Homebrew has their own [support site](https://discourse.brew.sh/c/linuxbrew) also.